# Guest OS stops responding to Mouse buttons and keyboard out of the blue vmware workstation

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, freeze

I am running Guest OS Ubuntu 12_04 on VMware Workstation 8.0.4 on Windows 7 Host.  I have been logged on for 4.5 hours doing some sort of heavy but not so heavy computation.  All of the sudden, I cannot access my open Terminator windows or click on anything on the left bar.  In one of my Terminator windows, I have an on-going process which is still running because I see output spit out occasionally.  I also see that the time on the upper bar for Ubuntu OS is updating properly.

So how can I regain focus of the Ubuntu OS?  I think it is most likely an OS thing and not a Mouse or Keyboard thing unless if I accidentally hit some sort of hotkey.  In my Windows 7 OS, my mouse and keyboard function just fine and I have tried to replug my mouse but no effect.

I cannot restart my Ubuntu OS at least until my running process has finished so I am looking for any way I can regain control of the Guest OS now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do do when Linux gui freezes](http://superuser.com/questions/171357/what-do-do-when-linux-gui-freezes)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Eclipse started to choke the Guest OS.  At first, none of the alt+ctrl+f(n) keys worked for me and so I thought that I needed a non-standard answer, but with persistence I was finally able to get a terminal so that with `ps -ef | more` I could see that it was eclipse and killed it with `kill -9`.  Now I have control once again of my Guest OS.